# How to Create a Scrollable Page With A ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following but I would like for the Text title to also scroll with the list. How to do this?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text("hello"),
        ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return UserWidget(
            firstName: userdetails[index]['first_name'],
            lastName: userdetails[index]['last_name'],
            imageURL: userdetails[index]['image_url'],
          );
        },
        itemCount: userdetails.length,
      ),
      ]
    );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter : How to add a Header Row to a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49986303/flutter-how-to-add-a-header-row-to-a-listview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your list with `Expanded` and add `shrinkWrap: true,` and `physics: ScrollPhysics(),` under `ListView`

### Scrolling without text title

```
Column(children: [
        Text("hello"),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: ScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text("$index"),
              );
            },
            itemCount: 50,
          ),
        ),
      ])
```

### Scrolling with text title

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(children: [
        Text("hello"),
        ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text("$index"),
            );
          },
          itemCount: 50,
        ),
      ]),
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a SingleChildScrollView and add listview and text as children of it

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView (
     child :Column(
      children: [
        Text("hello"),
        ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return UserWidget(
            firstName: userdetails[index]['first_name'],
            lastName: userdetails[index]['last_name'],
            imageURL: userdetails[index]['image_url'],
          );
        },
        itemCount: userdetails.length,
       physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),
      ]
    )
  );
}
```